# How can we conditionally load a vendor css with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

For example, if we have a **vendor** scss file named `vendor.scss` with the following content:

```
$color: green;

h1 {
  background-color: $color;
}
```

How can we write the rules to achieve to following result? (Or similar)

```
let vendor = true; // this will be configured outside

if (vendor) {
  let style = require('style-loader/useable!css-loader!./vendor.scss');
  style.use(); //loads just if I call `use`, otherwise not
}

require('my-other-file.scss'); // loads normally, without `use`.
```

Because `vendor.scss` is a vendor scss/css we cannot or should not rename it to, for example, `vendor.useable.scss`.
And for maintaining purposes we would like to not create a new one like `my-vendor-wrapper.scss` that could wrap it with an `@import` inside of it.

In webpack, for now, I have this rule:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  // test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
  test: /^(?!.*style-loader\/useable!).*\.(sass|scss|css)$/i,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
  })
}
```

I tried several things, like creating additional rules.
If I use an custom extension like lscss (for lazy scss) I can put it to work.
But the expected behavior that I would like is load all css/scss normally but if it have `style-loader/useable!` in front of it just loads if I call `use`.

How can we do this?

Comment: Did you try dynamic imports?

Comment: @Ivan can you share a link with me?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/